# Passing a boolean R vector to C dynamic_bitset

Tags: c++, r, rcpp

What is the best way to pass an R vector of booleans to a C++ `dynamic_bitset` vector? Is there a way to use a pointer and the vector length to construct a `dynamic_bitset` object as would be possible for the vector class? Would you recommend using Rcpp ?
Thanks for your help and time...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would just create the `dynamic_bitset` like this:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
#include <boost/dynamic_bitset.hpp>

using namespace Rcpp ;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
void create_dynamic_bitset( LogicalVector x ){  
    int n = x.size() ;
    boost::dynamic_bitset<> bs(n);
    for( int i=0; i<n; i++) bs[i] = x[i] ;

    // do something with the bitset
    for (boost::dynamic_bitset<>::size_type i = 0; i < x.size(); ++i)
        Rcout << x[i];
    Rcout << "\n";

}
```

Internally, R logical vectors are just `int` arrays. So there is not a more direct way to construct the `dynamic_bitset`, you *have* to iterate.

Also, beware of missing values in your input `LogicalVector`.

Alternatively, you might have the input data stored as a raw vector (Rcpp class `RawVector`), use a `dynamic_bitset<Rbyte>` and use the block constructor:

```
void create_dynamic_bitset( RawVector x ){  
    boost::dynamic_bitset<Rbyte> bs(x.begin(), x.end());
}
```

Comment: Nice and +1. I tossed a an `Rcpp::export` attribute in there so that it is actually callable from R :)

Comment: Initially I tried to use `BH`but apparently `dynamic_bitset` is not included, so no showcase of `Rcpp::depends(BH)`

Comment: We upgraded the package yesterday ... but it is still missing.  You too are an author of BH so if you want it in there you could alter the package creation script.